# How to display a class attribute in an array Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this code in my haml file.

```
      = f.select :rate_type, options_for_select(@rate_type, @selected_rate_type), required: true, :style => 'width:125px'
```

I want to however

```
def new

    @payer_contract = PayerContract.new(
         id: '',
         description: '',
         type_code: {
             id: '',
             code_key: '',
             display: '',
             code_group: ''
    },
         base_contract_rate: '',
         phase_dates: [{
                           id: '',
                           rate_type: '',
                           institutional: '',
                           professional: ''
                       }],
         donor_claim_phase: '',
         stoploss_amount: '',
         stoploss_reimbursement_percentage: '',
         begin_date: '',
         end_date: '',
         timely_filing_days: '',
         payer: '',
         rate_type: ''
    )
```

select phase_dates[rate_type], not just rate_type. I've tried doing this,

```
      = f.select :@phase_date.rate_type, options_for_select(@rate_type, @selected_rate_type), required: true, :style => 'width:125px'
```

but it does not work. Any idea what the syntax for this is?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
= f.select :rate_type, options_for_select(@rate_type, @selected_rate_type), { required: true }, { :style => 'width:125px' }
```

Look at the [select documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for more informaiton.